# Wordpress Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, memory, e-commerce

I'm trying to learn wordpress by creating an e-commerce website every time I load the web page I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-widgets/category_widget.php on line 61

So far I have tried the following:

putting this at the top of the wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

and putting this at the top of the .htaccess file

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

I can't even access wp-login.php page as it throws the same error.

Comment: See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+Allowed+memory+size

Comment: @brasofilo I have read this post but it is suggesting I should do things that require signing into the admin section of wordpress. Unfortunately, I can't even access wp-login.php page as it throws the same error

Comment: Connect via FTP, rename the plugins folder (`/wp-content/plugins`) to `plugins-old` and try to connect. Will probably work. Then rename the folder back and go enabling the plugins one by one. If not, do the same with the themes folder.

Comment: ahh brilliant thank you! Fixed it now, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll be more than happy to accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the admin is inaccessible, the first step is to connect via FTP and rename the folder `wp-content/plugins` to *`plugins-old`* and try to connect.

It will probably work. Then rename the folder back and go enabling the plugins one by one until you find the culprit. If not, do the same with the themes folder.

Useful info:

- [Troubleshooting Master List](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list)
- [Similar posts at WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fatal%20error:%20Allowed%20memory%20size)